# Trying to create a dependent combobox in yii using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii, combobox, yii-extensions

I am trying to create a dependent combobox system in my Yii application.
First combobox is populated with States and the second one is dynamically generated with *ajax* and *renderPartial()* method.
Code below:

**View**

```
<?php
$this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
    'model' => $adMulti,
    'attribute' => 'state_id',
    // data to populate the select. Must be an array.
    'data' => CHtml::listData(State::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
    'assoc' => true,
    // options passed to plugin
    'options' => array(
        // JS code to execute on 'select' event, the selected item is
        // available through the 'item' variable.
        'onSelect' => 'getCities(item.value);',
        // If false, field value must be present in the select.
        // Defaults to true.
        'allowText' => false,
    ),
    // Options passed to the text input
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'style' => 'height: 36px',
    ),
));
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getCities(state) {
      $.ajax({
          url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('ad/ajaxCities'); ?>',
          data: {state_name: state},
          type: 'POST',
          success: function (data) {
              $('#city_id-carrier').html(data);
          }
      });
  }
</script>
<div id="city_id-carrier" class="textboxes"></div>
```

**AdController**

```
public function actionAjaxCities()
    {
        $stateName = isset($_POST['state_name']) ? $_POST['state_name'] : FALSE;
        if ($stateName) {
            $state = State::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                'name' => $stateName
            ));
            $stateId = $state->id;
            $cities = City::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(
               'state_id' => $stateId
            ));
            $this->renderPartial('_cities', array(
                'cities' => $cities,
                'stateId' => $stateId
                ), FALSE, TRUE
            );
        }
    }
```

**_cities.php**

```
<?php
$this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
    'model' => AdMulti::model(),
    'attribute' => 'city_id',
    // data to populate the select. Must be an array.
    'data' => CHtml::listData($cities, 'id', 'name'),
    'assoc' => true,
    // options passed to plugin
    'options' => array(
        // JS code to execute on 'select' event, the selected item is
        // available through the 'item' variable.
        // 'onSelect' => 'getLocalities(item.value);',
        // If false, field value must be present in the select.
        // Defaults to true.
        'allowText' => false,
    ),
));
?>
```

The code is working and creating the combobox for the first time. But when I change the value in *state* combobox, something weird happens. A new combobox is created, but the values shown are still from the first combobox generated.
I am getting an error "TypeError: this.input is undefined" in Firebug Console.

I tried creating unique id for combobox using *uniqid()* but it isn't affecting the id of *select* element of the combobox.

If I change

```
$('#city_id-carrier').html(data)
```

to

```
$('#city_id-carrier').append(data)
```

it is working well but with multiple combobox generated.

Any ideas/suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to get this working. Instead of creating the combobox dynamically, place the combobox once and then populate it dynamically upon each request. Much like [dependent dropdown](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/).
A combobox is a combination of a dropdown and textbox. So, note down the id of the hidden dropdown and update it upon ajax update.

Code:

**View:**

```
<?php
    $this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
        'model' => $adMulti,
        'attribute' => 'state_id',
        // data to populate the select. Must be an array.
        'data' => CHtml::listData(State::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
        'assoc' => true,
        // options passed to plugin
        'options' => array(
            // JS code to execute on 'select' event, the selected item is
            // available through the 'item' variable.
            'onSelect' => 'getCities(item.value);',
            // If false, field value must be present in the select.
            // Defaults to true.
            'allowText' => false,
        ),
    ));
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function getCities(state) {
          $.ajax({
              url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('ad/ajaxCities'); ?>',
              data: {state_id: state},
              type: 'POST',
              beforeSend: function() {
                  $('#AdMulti_city_id_combobox').val(''); // emptying textbox in case a value is previously selected.
              },
              success: function (data) {
                  $('#AdMulti_city_id').html(data); // populating the hidden dropdown.
              }
          });
      }
  </script>
<?php
$this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
    'model' => $adMulti,
    'attribute' => 'city_id',
    // data to populate the select. Must be an array.
    'data' => CHtml::listData(array(''), 'id', 'name'),
    'assoc' => true,
    // options passed to plugin
    'options' => array(
        'allowText' => false,
    ),
));
?>
```

**AdController**

```
    public function actionAjaxCities()
    {
        $stateName = isset($_POST['state_id']) ? $_POST['state_id'] : FALSE;
        if ($stateName) {
            $state = State::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                'name' => $stateName
            ));
            $cities = City::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(
               'state_id' => $state->id
            ));
            $data = CHtml::listData($cities, 'id', 'name');
            foreach ($data as $id => $name) {
                echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $id),
                    CHtml::encode($name), TRUE);
            }
        }
    }
```